# Xcode - What is transition Gmail use to swipe left-right to next-previous mail item

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, gmail

I use Gmail and like the way to view next - previous mail by swipe left-right when in detailview of an email item. I'm writing some application and want to make the apps like that. What is transition between two detailviews that Gmail used? And what is animation be used?
When i swipe, current view will scroll out and next view also scroll in like two view are sequential with other.
But, in fact, two views be init by the same `DetailViewController`.
I read some tutorial, but not found solution. I think that is `UISplitViewController`??
[image]

Comment: Curious to know - were you able to figure out a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something that's called Custom View Controller Transitions.

Long story shot, you'll need to:
1) Create a create a class that conforms to `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` protocol. There you'll write your animation code. Don't forget to call `transitionContext. completeTransition (true)` when you your animation is done.

To trigger a custom transition, your `UINavigationController` have to implement `UINavigationControllerDelegate` method protocol: `func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerForOperation operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, fromViewController fromVC: UIViewController,toViewController toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?` and return the object that you created in 1) (The one which conforms to UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning).

Returning `nil` will trigger the default animation `push`, `pop` and so on.

Have a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/#218) WWDC Session which explains how to use it.
I strongly recommend you reading [this issue](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html) too.

Comment: @kdopen, sorry! Looking better now?

Comment: Can't you use a simple PageViewController for this? It doesn't seem like a different ViewController since the Navigation bar doesn't change.